# How to add one folder in classpath for ant script?

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I need to add a folder in current classpath for ant script that I have written for running java files. How can it be done?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704324/how-to-add-to-classpath-all-classes-from-set-of-directories-in-ant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i added the following line in the  tag of the task and it ran successfully.

```
<pathelement path="C:\JunitTest\folderIsHere"/>
```

and after this the script ran successfully.

Answer (score 8):

You could add it as an attribute

```
<java classpath="${extraDir}"
      classname="pkg.Class">
      ...
</java>
```

Or using the nested `<classpath>` tag:

```
<java classname="pkg.Class">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement path="${extraDir}"/>
  </classpath>
</java>
```

See the documentation for [the Java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Comment: actually i hv some xml files, which i hv placed them all in a folder, if i trying to gv the folder path, then also ant is unable to pick it up.

Comment: You should probably look into the [import task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html)